# How can I get current URI from Symfony 1.4?

Tags: symfony1, symfony-1.4

I am new to symfony.

How can I get from Symfony 1.4 the URI path ?

I have tryied like that:

```
sfContext::getInstance()->getRequest()->getRelativeUrlRoot()
```

but is not working.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

getCurrentInternalUri is, like his name tell, the **internal** URL, to be used in internal routing functions such as link_to.

The question is about the **current URI** and even if the previous answer is marked as accepted, here is the method to fetch the current URI in symfony 1.4.

```
$context->getRequest()->getUri();
```

In an action :

```
public function executeDelete(sfWebRequest $request)
{
  $uri = $request->getUri();
}
```

Comment: I think it should be $sf_context->getRequest()->getUri();
Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 12):

Like this:

```
sfContext::getInstance()->getRouting()->getCurrentInternalUri();
```

This one might be of use too:

```
sfContext::getInstance()->getRouting()->getCurrentRouteName();
```

http://www.symfony-project.org/gentle-introduction/1_4/en/09-Links-and-the-Routing-System#chapter_09_dealing_with_routes_in_actions

**UPDATE:**

Please see Damien's answer below and im3r3k's comment for what seems to be a better method as it does not rely on context.